# How to use Oauth2 access token of auth server to authorize users in resource/app server?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am implementing SSO with laravel/lumen applications. I have the followings.

1. Auth server on laravel (central user directory, OAuth2 using laravel/passport)
2. Resource server on lumen (web app, no user table)
3. Client side JS app (ReactJS)

The workflow:

1. Login button on Client takes to auth server, oauth2 client is authorized by user and get `auth_code` and redirect back to client.
2. Client then uses POST request to send data to recourse server, which then gets the `access_token`, `refresh_token` from auth server.
3. **Next step is to authorize** user on resource server (App server) using the auth server `access_token`. I need it to be stateless (JWT?)

Here is a flowchart in details:

[image]

Comment: I know that this is old, but for someone else looking for a solution to a similar problem - this package solves this problem. Actually it's inspired by this topic. [Laravel SSO package](https://github.com/revenuefm/ssoguard)

Answer (score 1):

After gaining `access_token` you have to send Authorization header back to auth server and there you may use a custom middleware or controller action to authenticate and authorize the user.

Simple workflow could be something like this:

Assuming you are sending HTTP requests to auth server API with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) library and the imaginary route is `api/user/authorize`, so in front-end app:

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `http://localhost:8000/api/user/authorize`,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
})
.then( response => {
    // stuff to do on success
})
.catch( error => {
    // stuff to do on failure
});
```

**routes/api.php:**

```
Route::get('user/authorize', 'UserController@isAuthorized');
```

**UserController.php:**

```
public function isAuthorized(Request $request)
{
  // Retrieving user based the on provided authorization header
  $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

  // In case of no-user
  if (!$user) {
    return response()->json([
      'isAuthorized' => false
    ], 401);
  }

  return response()->json([
    'isAuthorized' => true
  ], 200);
}
```

and this can be done in many other ways as well. Hope you get the idea!

Comment: I am looking for authorizing user to the **resource server** not in the auth server. User is already authorized in the auth server as the auth server has returned the access_token.

Comment: No difference, I just represented a simple workflow! You've provided _username_ and _password_ and got `access_token` from auth server. From now on you should attach that token to every HTTP request you're going to make to App server. Then you need to forward the header to auth server to authorize the user..

Comment: okay, I understand that part. But how the app server authorize/validate the same access token against itself?

Comment: Since _users_ table is located at _auth server_, you can not perform authorization in _app server_. So,  1) client app should retrieve `access_token` from _auth server_ 2) client app should attach an `authorization header` to request 3) cleint app should send the request to _app server_ 4) _app server_ should send a http request to _auth server_ with the provided `authorization header` 5) _auth server_ then process the request and send a response back to _app server_ 6) If user is authorized based on _auth server's_ response, then _app server_ process the user's request

Comment: 7) If not, an error will send to client. One of the most popular libraries for sending HTTP request from PHP is [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Comment: Understood, Does the handshake with auth server need to be in every app server resource call?